# How trim/remove time from vue el-date-picker?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I use the following code ([documentation](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/date-picker)):

```
<el-date-picker
    v-model="myModel"
    type="date"
    placeholder="Pick a date" />
```

And I got va;ue with time like that - `2019-06-15T17:00:00.000Z`

Are there data-picker settings to change format to `2019-06-15` or `2019-06-15T00:00:00.000Z` ?

Answer (score 1):

The `format` attribute will only control the display shown, but you can use the `value-format` attribute to use a string instead of a date object.

```
<template>
<el-date-picker
      v-model="value"
      type="date"
      format="yyyy/MM/dd"
      value-format="yyyy-MM-dd">
</el-date-picker>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
      return {
        value: ''
      };
    }
  };
</script>
```

Source:
https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/date-picker#date-formats

Comment: I think this is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the response date and then use JavaScript to convert that with:

```
date.getMonth() // 5 (starts with 0) so use +1 
date.getDate() // 15 
date.getFullYear() // 2019
```

Would that work in your case?

The library you are using also uses `value-format` to control what is saved.

Answer (score 0):

```
<el-date-picker
    v-model="myModel"
    type="date"
    placeholder="Pick a date"
    format="yyyy-MM-dd" />
```